# Bootstrap. Keep active class on new page

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have faced a problem with adding "active" class to my tabs.
I know how to add active class to tab when i click on it. But i don't know how to save active class on tab after page reload.

Part of my jsp code

```html
<div class="row top-buffer">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 products">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills cat-nav">
            <c:forEach items="${catList}" var="category">
                <li role="presentation" >
                    <a href="/show-category?id=${category.id}" >${category.name}</a>
                    <ul class="dropdownn">
                        <c:forEach items="${category.childCategories}" var="childCat">
                            <li><a href="/show-category?id=${childCat.id}">${childCat.name}</a> </li>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </c:forEach>
            <li role="presentation" class="pull-right"><a href="/show-category?id=0">All</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script for adding active class

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.cat-nav li a').click(function(e) {

        $('.cat-nav li').removeClass('active');

        var $parent = $(this).parent();
        if (!$parent.hasClass('active')) {
            $parent.addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

When i click on link it send me to another page, but that another page has no active class. So how can i "save" or "hold" active class and put in in new page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have solved it !

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var id = getParameterByName('id');

    $('.cat-nav li[role="presentation"]').each(function() {

        var id2 = $(this).attr("id");

        if(id == id2){
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});

function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';

    localStorage.setItem(name, results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    var result = localStorage.getItem("id");
    return result;
}
```

```html
<div class="row top-buffer">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 products">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills cat-nav">
            <c:forEach items="${catList}" var="category">
                <li role="presentation" id="${category.id}">
                    <a href="/show-category?id=${category.id}" >${category.name}</a>
                    <ul class="dropdownn">
                        <c:forEach items="${category.childCategories}" var="childCat">
                            <li><a href="/show-category?id=${childCat.id}">${childCat.name}</a> </li>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </c:forEach>
            <li role="presentation" class="pull-right" id="0"><a href="/show-category?id=0">All</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your click handler you are adding and removing the 'active' class on the `<li>` element.  In bootstrap the 'active' class is applied to the `<a>` element instead.  With a small adjustment to your code this works:

```
$('.cat-nav li a').click(function() {
     $('.cat-nav li a').removeClass('active');
     $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Link to example in codepen:
http://codepen.io/johnwilson/pen/akVgxq

Comment: Thx for tying to help me. But it didn't solve my problem. I will try to describe my problem more clearly. Every tab has link to another page. And all those pages have same tab panel. Yes, when i click on tab in becomes "active" for a second, then it load new page, and new page has no active class. I want to save this active class on new page.

Comment: Save that active indication/flag in cookie at client side or passing as query string to your new page. Of course you then need read those flags when loading new page. Or you should consider re-design how it should works.